# Django database sqlite display of value of attribute

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I'm on a project using django and I wrote my models.py

I have two classes

```
class Adresse(models.Model):
    numV=models.IntegerField(blank=False,null=False)
    complementdest=models.TextField(blank=False,null=False)
    complementadr=models.TextField(blank=False,null=False)
    commune=models.TextField(blank=False,null=False)
    codeP=models.IntegerField(blank=False,null=False)
    pays=models.TextField(blank=False,null=False)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.numV
        return self.complementdest
        return self.complementadr
        return self.commune
        return self.codeP
        return self.pays
    def __Adr__(self):
        return self.adr1.all()
```

and

```
class CompteCandidat(myUser):
    sexe = models.TextField(max_length=10)
    datecr = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    adresse=models.OneToOneField('Adresse',related_name='adr1',null=True, default=None)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name
        return self.last_name
        return self.email
        return self.sexe
    def __Adr__(self):
        return self.adresse.all()
```

I try to do some tests like this:

> > > adresse=Adresse(numV='254',complementdest='xxxxx',complementadr='Eugene napoleon',commune='Paris',codeP='75012',pays='France')
> > >
> > > c1=CompteCandidat(username='Luna',first_name='celia',last_name='durand',password='CCC',email='hello2@gmail.com',type='candidat',adresse=adresse)
> > >       adresse.save()
> > >       c1.save()

and when I try to see what I have in my Adresse or in my CompteCandidat by using this command it didn't work

```
>>> Adresse.__getattribute__(numV)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'numV' is not defined
```

i want to know what i'm suppose to do to display what I have in Adresse and CompteCandidat in order to be sure that the add works

i know i Can do :

```
>>> adresse.numV
'254'
```

but it works only in the console there is an another way to consult all the database without using the name of the temporery variables ????

Comment: This is really unclear. What are you trying to do with that get attribute call?

Comment: Plus, you should not be calling double-underscore methods directly, and you should *never* define your own arbitrary ones.

Comment: I try to call the attribute numV in

Comment: >>> Adresse.__getattribute__(numV) and the response of the console was : Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'numV' is not defined

Comment: thank you, so how can I call to display and verify my database ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use
`Adresse.objects.all()`
 to see all records or `Adresse.object.filter(numV='254)`
 to see records satisfying this  condition.
For full reference please check:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/ja/1.9/topics/db/queries/

Comment: I try this and i have this error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Sourour Bnll\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 237, in __repr__
    return repr(data)
  File "C:\Users\Sourour Bnll\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 459, in __repr__
    u = six.text_type(self)
TypeError: __str__ returned non-string (type int)

Comment: so i try to delete from __str__ this two: return self.numV and self.codeP but the error is the same

Comment: Oooh, you're trying to put IntegerFields strings, most probably it is because of that.

Comment: i delete itfrom str this two: return self.numV and self.codeP but the error is the same

Comment: you have multiple return statements in your ``__str__`` method - you don't need them.

Answer (score 0):

At first in the console try this:

```
>>>A = {numV='254',complementdest='xxxxx',complementadr='Eugene napoleon',commune='Paris',codeP='75012',pays='France'}
>>> adresse = Adresse(**A)
>>> adresse.save()
```

At first you will face an error beacuse your `numV` is `Integer` but you are assigning an `String` to it, so should edit `numV = '254'` to `numV = 254` at first line.

Then try above steps again and post that in which step face error.

Answer (score 0):

Two things :

1. `__str__` must only return a single string - as it stands your code tries to return multiple non string values.
2. the `__getattribute__` method (and it's counterpart `getattr`) should be passed the name of the attribute i.e. a string.  Also you shouldn't be trying to call `__getattribute__` directly except in exceptional circumstances: ie. you have some form of circular access confilct - which you don't here.

There is no reason that `adresse.numV` shouldn't work directly in your code - that is the normal way to retrieve attributes from an instance. You should only use `getattr` if you have the attribute name in a string from elsewhere.

At the risk of sounding rude - if you are struggling to write code that correctly accesses attributes then maybe trying to write a Django App is a case of trying to run before you walk.